# Outlook addin: On NewMail handler with dispatch pointer

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, atl

I am working on outlook addin

I am having following calls which calls when New mail comes and if user sents mail.

```
void __stdcall OnNewMail();
void __stdcall OnSend(IDispatch * item, bool cancel);
```

BEGIN_SINK_MAP(CAddin)
SINK_ENTRY_INFO(1,__uuidof(Outlook::ApplicationEvents),/*dispinterface*/0x0000F002,OnSend,&OnSendInfo)
SINK_ENTRY_INFO(2,__uuidof(Outlook::ApplicationEvents),/*dispinterface*/0x0000F003,OnNewMail,&OnNewMailInfo)
END_SINK_MAP()

which works fine.

now i want same ( IDispatch * item ) in case of NewMail notification handler.

if i put as like this:

```
_ATL_FUNC_INFO OnNewMailInfo = {CC_STDCALL, VT_EMPTY, 0, { VT_DISPATCH | VT_BOOL }};
void __stdcall OnNewMail(IDispatch * item, bool cancel);
```

i am  getting IDispatch NULL pointer also it crashes once it goes out of OnNewMail Function.

Please suggest where i am going wrong.

your revert is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the "OnNewMailInfo"-structure is not correct. The third field is the number of parameters passed to the function (according to the signature), the fourth is an array of VT_...-constants. So it should be

```
_ATL_FUNC_INFO OnNewMailInfo = {CC_STDCALL, VT_EMPTY, 2, { VT_DISPATCH, VT_BOOL }};
void __stdcall OnNewMail(IDispatch * item, bool cancel);
```